# Image not displaying when uploaded online

Tags: html

I found other posts, but they did not resolve my issue.

The code I have is

```
<img src="Images/myphoto.jpg" width="300" height="263" alt="photo">
```

I have checked several times and the image folder is in the root directory and the image is inside it, but online I get a broken image icon and the alt text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Got a URL we can see?

Comment: And the file with the code is also inside root directory? If no, you have to add slash at the before `Images/myphoto.jpg`.

Comment: A live URL would most certainly help in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference the root directory, start your relative url with a frontslash.  As it is now, it's looking for a relative path from the current url, not the root url.

```
<img src="/Images/myphoto.jpg" width="300" height="263" alt="photo">
```